# Angular 2 Http Get always returning XML in Firefox, should be JSON

Tags: angular

I am trying to call a Web Api endpoint from Angular 2. 
In IE and Chrome it all works fine but in Firefox I get a json parse error.
I think its returning XML instead of Json. 
I thought that setting the content-type would have fixed this. 
Does my code look correct? Any ideas?

```
    let _tileUrl = XXX;

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this._http.get(_tileUrl, options)
        .map((response: Response) => <ITile[]>response.json())
                 .catch(this.handleError);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you should use the `Accept` header instead:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this._http.get(_tileUrl, options)
    .map((response: Response) => <ITile[]>response.json())
             .catch(this.handleError);
```

The `Content-Type` header describes the type of content you send. `Accept` the content you expect in the response...

Answer (score 2):

If you want this request to be the default for all of your HTTP requests, you can set the default RequestOptions in your bootstrap call, like so:

```
import { RequestOptions, BaseRequestOptions } from "@angular/http";

...

class AppBaseRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
    // Overriding Accept so that Firefox will correctly get JSON 
    // responses from the server rather than XML.
    public headers: Headers = new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    });
}

bootstrap(AppRoot, [ ...
     { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: AppBaseRequestOptions }
]);
```